# rails upgrade 3 : No method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-3-upgrade

I just upgraded my app from 2.3.11 to 3.0.6. I want to upgrade it further to rails 3.2. After upgrading it 3.0.6, I got this error message 
https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/PlotApp/blob/rails3/error_message.txt

I could not come up with a possible answer as why this no method error is coming up? How can I resolve this?  I have checked previous similar questions like this but could not find a solution for my case.

Comment: Please show source of plots_controller.

Comment: https://github.com/kumarsaurabh20/PlotApp/blob/rails3/app/controllers/plots_controller.rb

The app is not complete yet..but this error was not expected while running it.